# Migrating database to SQL Server 2008, maintaining compatibility level 80 - issues?

Tags: sql-server-2008, compatibility-level

I need to migrate the database in a vendor-supplied client-server application to SQL Server 2008.  The version of the application we run is supported on SQL Server 2000 SP4 and SQL Server 2005 SP2, but not 2008 - the reason, however, is mainly because the vendor wants us to upgrade to the current version (which is planned for 1Q/2Q 2014), and didn't want to "enable" us to stay on an old version of the app.

My question is, if I restore the database on SQL Server 2008 with compatibility level 80, and don't make any changes to it (it's a vendor database), what issues could arise?  I understand that I can't restore the DB down to 2005/2000 - that won't be necessary.  I'm more concerned about what may have been coded into procs that assumes 2005 or below - I've found one example so far, and amending the version statement (@@version = "SQL Server 2008") did the trick.  What else is out there to think about?  FYI - only standard database objects are being used - no jobs, DTS, SSRS, SSIS, etc.  In addition, I'm done extensive application testing logged into 2008 with no issues so far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Since your question is more about backend administration of a database engine, I've recommended that it be moved to dba.se.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I highly doubt anything in their app *relies* on 80 compatibility, and think it is highly unlikely that anything will break if you move to 90 or 100. This is usually just a way for a vendor to delay having to do elaborate testing of their old app against a newer version of SQL Server, especially if - as you say - they have a new version coming out.

However, there isn't much we can do to guide you on whether their app will break on a newer compat level. We have no idea what code they're using and what 80-specific features they're using. For example, they could be using old-style outer join syntax (`FROM a, b WHERE a.x *= b.x`) which will break in > 80.

I think the safest approach would be to take a full backup of the database, restore a copy to 2008, move it to **90** compatibility (since that is the latest *version* they support), or **100** if you are feeling frisky, and then test the heck out of a ***copy*** of the app. Chances are they are being overly conservative by not supporting the new version, but there won't be any negative outcome. If a full regression and compatibility test works out okay, then you should be able to upgrade your app.